# -replace not replacing quotations

Tags: powershell, csv, replace

I have a CSV file that on random lines will contain quotation marks. Example of data is:

```
example1:yes:no
"example2:no:no"
"example3:yes:yes"
example4:no:yes
```

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
$newCsvPath = Get-Content -Path .\allsystems.csv  
$newCsvPath -replace '"',""
```

Yet it keeps the quotations in as if the second line was never there. Am I using this wrong?

Comment: You mean that allsystems.csv keeps the quotes, or you actually have quotes being printed to the console when you do -replace?

Comment: When these two lines are ran, `$newCsvPath` contains all the same information from `allsystems.csv`, including the quotation marks. So it is printing the quotes

Comment: `-replace` doesn't replace in-place. You need to assign the result back to the variable: `$newCsvPath = $newCsvPath -replace '"',""`.

Comment: ^That solved it, thank you

Comment: From the example csv I cannot make out why some lines have qoutes while others don't. Perhaps you're not showing us enough.. Anyway, it is extremely dangerous to just go ahead and remove quotes in a csv file, because usually they are there for a good reason, namely so that the parser knows everything between the quotes belongs to the same field even if it contains the delimiter character or newline. Use the answer HAL9256 gave you and if needed save the `$newCsvPath` to a **new** file using the `Export-Csv` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a true CSV file, instead of using `Get-Content`, use `Import-CSV`. It will handle all the quotation marks and everything for you.

```
$newCsvPath = Import-CSV -Path .\allsystems.csv
```